# Firefox 43 Mac Selenium Error

Tags: python, macos, firefox, selenium, jupyter-notebook

I run a python script which contains selemium webdriver package every month.

After the update of Firefox, I am getting the following error:

> WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s
>   If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it
>   for details.

Do you have any idea what I have to do? I tried to update selenium but for some reason I have the same package version.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have updated the selenium package using the following command.

```
sudo pip install -U selenium
```

It didn't work before due to a permission error, so I had to add sudo before I execute the above command.
I took the answer from another stackoverflow post, which had the same question but for older version of the Firefox.